# How to Align div's horizontally such as text within gets ellipsed

Tags: javascript

I have 2 div's which have some text in them. They are encapsulated within a parent Div which has fixed height and width. I want to ellipse the text if they overflow outside the parent div.

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    .pDiv {
        width:50px;
        height:20px;
        border: 1px  solid red;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .div1 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .div2 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class ='pDiv'>
        <div class ='div1'>test testing</div>
        <div class ='div2'>test1</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the text to be ellipsed if either the div1 text is long or the div2 text is long.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The ellipses don't show because the div1 and div2 don't have widths assigned to them, and as such they don't know at what point to begin truncating/abbreviating. Perhaps you could assign 100% width to each. That is, if you add
    `width:100%`
to both of the classes, you'll see ellipsis on the text.

I would suggest taking a look at the following link: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html which describes the issue and requirements thereof.